# Prioritizing case in mysql

Tags: mysql, list, case

I want to prioritize the status part. Everything which is not repported should appear first. Regardless date. But now, It orders eveything after date. How can I prioritize the first case 'not repported part'? The rest of the list should appear after date.

```
SELECT * FROM list
        ORDER BY date DESC, 
CASE 
        WHEN `bookings`.`status` = 'Not repported'  THEN 1 
        WHEN day= 'Monday' THEN 2 
        WHEN day= 'Tuesday' THEN 3 
        WHEN day= 'Wednesday' THEN 4 
        WHEN day= 'Thursdau' THEN 5 
        WHEN day= 'Friday' THEN 6 
        WHEN day= 'Saturday' THEN 7 WHEN 
        day= 'Sunday' THEN 8 END ASC 
        limit 1,20 ";
```

I want something like this.

```
------------------------------
DATE----DAY-------STATUS------
2011---Monday-----Not reported
2015---Sunday-----Not reported
2010---Wednedday--Not reported
2016---Monday---------Reported
2015---Monday---------Reported
2014---Tuesday--------Reported
2013---Sunday---------Reported
------------------------------
```

Comment: As a note, storing days as literal names like this is extremely messy. You'd be much better off storing them as values like 1..7 to mesh up with functions like [`DAYOFWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek). A sterling example of why not to do this is your code cannot handle anything done on Thursday and tracking down that bug could be an exercise in utter frustration.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not help me to prioritize the not repported part.

Comment: you might want to post the expected output rather speculate

Comment: Before you get too married to your misspelling, it's "reported".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order by
Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM list
        ORDER BY  
CASE 
        WHEN `bookings`.`status` = 'Not repported'  THEN 1  ELSE 2 
END,

CASE
        WHEN day= 'Monday' THEN 2 
        WHEN day= 'Tuesday' THEN 3 
        WHEN day= 'Wednesday' THEN 4 
        WHEN day= 'Thursdau' THEN 5 
        WHEN day= 'Friday' THEN 6 
        WHEN day= 'Saturday' THEN 7 WHEN 
        day= 'Sunday' THEN 8 END ASC,

date DESC
        limit 1,20 ";
```

This will give you this result

'Not repported' , 1/1/2017

'Not repported' , 3/7/2017

'Not repported' , 15/8/2017

Monday          , 6/2/2017

Monday          , 11/11/2017

Comment: It priotizes the date. It doesn't lift up all the 'not reported' rows to the begining of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You have two order statements. One for the date, and one for your booking status. Mysql will first order according to your first order statement, and then according to your second order statement. So switching the order statements solves your problem. In addition there is the "ELSE" keyword for "CASE"s in mysql.

In total I would write it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM list
ORDER BY  
    CASE 
        WHEN `bookings`.`status` = 'Not repported'  THEN 1 
        ELSE 2
    END ASC,
    date DESC
LIMIT 1,20
```

(Im not so sure where your "bookings" table now comes from, but I left it there. You might miss a JOIN clause)

Comment: Thanks. But it does not help me to prioritize the not repported part.

Comment: Im sorry, but I do not understand. This should order everything according to the booking state (not reported first) and within this ordering, according to date. Could you maybe update your initial question with an example of your table and what you would like to have in the end?

Comment: I edited my post now. It is how I want it to look like.

Comment: @J.Doe and how this answer is not helpful?

Comment: I simply want to prioritize the not reported part. Whatever I do, the date is being prioritized. I don't want that.

Comment: @J.Doe this query would sort by the `bookings.status = 'Not repported'` first, then by `date DESC`

Comment: @zerkms I need to include date for the rest of the list. Not for the "unreported" rows.

Comment: "I need to include date for the rest of the list" --- what does this mean?

Comment: @zerkms I have had the date at the end of all queries. It did not help.

Comment: @zerkms  the rest of the list are the rows which are reported. They should be listed by date.

Comment: They are ordered by date desc. Not sure I understand what "listed by date" means.